# File upload with other form fields(Like Text inputs) in struts 1.3

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

I am trying to upload an Excel file onto my server. There is one more form field which I need, the Sheet Name. Now i have to use the org.apache.struts.upload to do this. But i am not able to figure out how i am going to extract the Sheet name text field since i cannot directly access request parameters on the multipart/form-data enctype.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, when someone answers your question, it's a good idea to either follow up if you didn't understand something, or vote up and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing request parameters directly in Struts 1, you should be using the `ActionForm` to encapsulate form values. All form values are available.

If you're not sure how to use the action form, [here's a tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-file-upload-example-1.html).